# While loop is running in a thread, yet it blocks the main gui

Tags: android

Why does this code block the main UI in the while loop?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someButton.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (HintergrundDienst.laeuft)
                {
                    //some delay code, like Thread.sleep
                }
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do on ui after HintergrundDienst.laeuft = false
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Running this blocks the main ui.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does this code block the main UI in the while loop?

Because it is running on the main application thread. Your loop is in a `Runnable` that you are providing to `post()`. [The documentation for `post()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) indicates that "The runnable will be run on the user interface thread". Here, "the user interface thread" refers to the the main application thread.